# Barclaycard ePDQ - custom user generated amounts

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway, sha, payment-processing

**Can you set up Barclaycard ePDQ to accept manual payments from customers? As opposed to using it for purely product based e-commerce purposes.**

***For example*** - customer a visits the website, clicks payment section, then enters the amount they want to pay for - e.g £121.50 - then on submit goes to Authorisation/Barclaycard section.

Is there a way that ePDQ can work in this format? I am familiar with how ePDQ would work with an online store but not for a service based business.

... I have read through the guides, forums and FAQ's to try and find out but can't find any further info on this and the support team are not responding, so hope someone can help! Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it won't.  But you can generate a pay by link email.  The recipient clicks on the link and is taken to the ePDQ payment page which is already pre-filled with the amount, ready to take the card details.  Don't know if this might fulfil your need.  You can set this up from the ePDQ back office.

You should be sending your emails to epdqsupport@barclaycard.co.uk. I'm confident you'll get a reply.

Comment: Thanks for answering, i'll try that way!